# Error when running "hello word" with Zeppelin-notebook

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I installed Zeppelin-0.6.0 on mac, everything is ok, and i don't modify anything with the configuration files, but when i run a command, it gets an error:[image][image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

when i brew uninstall the node i installed before, and replace it with node.pkg which i download from https://nodejs.org/en/. After this, everything works well.

Comment: It seems more than a problem with nodejs. The error you have telling that Zeppelin could not connect with the interpreter. Have you checked if the interpreter is already started?

Comment: you are right, i installed zeppelin on one spark cluster, and this error appeared again. I am sure I started the Zeppelin, and markdown and shell works well, i can't figure out why spark didn't work and always cast this error.

Comment: Could you check in your logs. By default they exist in `/PATH/TO/ZEPPELIN/logs`, both .out and .log files. You may find something there

Comment: I checked the logs files before, but i still couldn't make out what was going wrong, The Spark Interpreter log file says some thing going wrong with the concurrent, could you get some clue from it?

Comment: So it is a probleme with connection to spark master as I could see. The solution might be here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33216640/1314742

Comment: Have you got your issue resolved? I m just curious :)

Comment: previous problem is due to that i configured the spark master with its IP address. When i changed the master with the master hostname, this error is resolved, but i encountered another problem, the error log showed that the hadoop conf class couldn't  be found.